# Create list of display fields and checkbox fields from a table column in Oracle Apex

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I am trying to create a list of display fields and checkbox fields from a table column in Oracle Apex. For example, let's say I have a Table A. These are the values stored in A.

```
ID Health Conditions 
-- -----------------
1  Heart Disease
2  High Blood Pressure
3  Diabetes
```

So now I want to display these 3 display fields associated with 3 checkboxes so the users can choose whether they have the above health conditions problems. If Table A has n values, then I can dynamically display n fields with n checkboxes. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I understood the problem, you should pre-populate table (which will contain info about those health conditions) and display the whole list as Interactive Grid (or Tabular Form, depending on Apex version you use).

It means that you'd store non-checked values as well (though, you could delete such rows on submit).

Alternatively, if you create an "empty" Interactive Grid page and let users **add rows**, and for each row select health condition they have, you'd store only selected values.

Yet another option is to create a page with shuttle item (or select list that allows multiple selections) so that user would select only desired values and store them. Drowback of such an approach is that all values are stored into the same column (read: it is not normalized) separated by colons. That's OK for selecting values, but causes problems later when you have to do something with it as you have to first split values into rows and then *do that something*.

Comment: In fact, I would want to store those non-check values as well. Basically I will store values of 'Y' or 'N' for all health conditions in my database. Now I solved this problem by using a checkbox list. Now another issue occurs, how do I convert the checkbox values into character of 'Y' or 'N' which will be stored in my database.

Comment: Checkbox is binary; either it is checked, or it is not. It doesn't really matter *what* you store, as long as you know what it means. Then you can display it (for example, in a report) by using DECODE (or CASE). If it is stored as 0/1, you'd `case when my_checkbox = 0 then 'No' else 'Yes' end`.